# How to reset Principal attributeMap in Apereo CAS 6.1.x？

Tags: reset, cas, apereo

I am a beginner of CAS. I want to reset Principal attributeMap after loging successfully, and no solution in similar questions. Can anyone help me? Thanks for your advice!

CAS Version:6.1.6

Answer (score 1):

> I want to reset Principal attributeMap after logging successfully, and no solution in similar questions.

The reason you can't *"find solution in similar questions"* is because,

1. It cannot be done without a great deal of coding.
2. It's a bad idea. You cannot change the verified subject identify after it has been verified. Once the credentials are verified and the attributes are collected, that collection is final.

Rather than asking what is possible, it would be best if you described *why* you want to do this, and then folks can help you with alternatives once your use case and objectives are clearer.